# Approve start date should be less then start date

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I need help in writing the formula:

I have the following fields in my custom object:

```
Approve_Date__c - date field 
Start_Date__c - datetime field
Hiring__c - checkbox
```

Validation:

If `Hiring__c` is checked (true) then validate `Approve_Date__c` should be `one day` before the `Start_Date__c`

If `Hiring__c` is unchecked (false) then no validation fires.

Tried the following:

```
Hiring__c > DATEVALUE(Start_Date__c ) +1
```

Comment: What does your formula currently look like? Show us and we'll help you correct it.

Comment: What error did you get when you tried that value in the formula editor?

Comment: @NickKahn if Hiring__c is a checkbox field than how can you compare date result in checkbox?

Comment: @Ricky: Yes you are correct, I updated my question with what I have tried, `Hiring__c > DATEVALUE(Start_Date__c ) +1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need:

```
AND(
    Hiring__c, Approval_Date__c != DATEVALUE(Start_Date__c) + 1
)
```

You can't compare any of these fields directly to each other, they're all different types! Using an `AND` clause starting with the checkbox means you only validate if it is checked, then you just need to convert your `Datetime` field to a `Date` value to compare it to what you already have.

Comment: I totally agree with what you are saying Adrian, but isn't it technically a best practice to state `Hiring__c = TRUE` or does it not really matter?

Comment: No, I actually think checking `BooleanField__c = true` is *almost* as bad as `IF(BooleanField__c, true, false)`. I find it redundant. @cmmoutes13

Comment: Hmm alright, I was just curious because that is how I do it on a daily basis. I guess it is a bit redundant. @Adrian

Answer (score 1):

First you need both fields in same data type, to do this function `DATEVALUE()` is used and then if the difference between two dates is not equal to one day and `Hiring__c` field is checked, then validation rule will show the error message.

In your case, you are trying to add integer to date field which is not allowed.

Try this

```
AND((DATEVALUE(Start_Date__c) - Approve_Date__c) <> 1,Hiring__c)
```